# Linux commands not recognized in ChromeOS based Virtual Machine

Tags: virtual-machine, google-chrome-os

I have a Virtual Machine Instance on Google Cloud, which is set up using ChromeOS. The basic Linux commands such as `apt`, `dpkg`, etc are not recognized.

Is there a workaround how to enable "Linux beta" for ChromeOS from terminal, or another solution how can I be able to run any sort of `apt-get` commands?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no other choice rather than removing the ChromeOS-based machine and recreate a new one either debian or ubuntu.